# ¿Cómo hacer una lista en html?

Tags: html

Hola soy nuevo en el foro y también en **HTML**. Estoy realizando un ejercicio simple que dice así:

> Crea tu primera pagina web con titulo de ventana, un encabezado y una
>   lista con al menos tres parrafos de distinto color.

Y lo he hecho así:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mi primera pagina</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
 
 <h3>Primera página web: Cambiando colores a texto:</h3>
 
 <p style="color: red"><b>1- Texto en rojo.</b></p>
 <p style="color: green"><b>2- Texto en verde.</b></p>
 <p style="color: blue"><b>3- Texto en azul.</b></p>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Pero me han dicho que la lista debe de ser de otra forma, a que se refiere? Hace lo que me piden......

Comment: http://www.manualweb.net/html/listas-html/ Te recomiendo usar Google. Google es tu amigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!Buenas, bienvenido a **StackOverflow**!

Aunque a primera vista si esta haciendo lo que pide el ejercicio, hay una forma de hacer una  lista automaticamente, y ademas, de distintas formas. Para ello debes de utilizar estas etiquetas:

`<ol>` y `<li>`

Tu ejercicio quedaría de esta forma, sin retocarte mucho el código:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mi primera pagina</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
 
 <h3>Primera página web: Cambiando colores a texto:</h3>
 
 <ol>

  <li value="1"><p style="color: red"><b>Texto en rojo.</b></p></li>

  <li><p style="color: green"><b>Texto en verde.</b></p></li>

  <li><p style="color: blue"><b>Texto en azul.</b></p></li>

 </ol>
 
</body>
</html>
```

En el primer `<li>` si observas, hay un atributo `value= "1"`.

Ahí se tiene que especificar el primer numero en el cual comenzara la lista, y cada apartado que quieras añadir simplemente hazlo con un `<li>` y el `value` se incrementara solo.

Te dejo una pagina de referencia donde explican 
como utilizar las distintas etiquetas de listas, te sera de utilidad:

[Enlace a Listas HTML](https://www.hazunaweb.com/curso-de-html/listas/)

Espero que te haya servido la explicación, y !mucha suerte aprendiendo!

Comment: Te faltan las `ul`

Comment: Las `ul` son para listas no ordenadas, según he entendido en la pregunta, el quiere ordenar. Pero igualmente le he dejado un enlace donde explican todo tipo de listas para que se vaya informando

Comment: valee ahora lo entiendo, muchas gracias por la informacion intentare aprender mejor de esto, es que no nos han explicado bien las cosas y querian que aprendieramos solos pero no tenia mucha idea

Comment: @Youshiro en ningun momento ha dicho que tengan que ser ordenadas.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente como tienes tu ejemplo no estás realizando una lista, con la etiqueta `<p>` estas haciendo párrafos.

Para la realización de la lista debes usar las etiquetas `<ol><li>`para listas numeradas de la siguiente forma:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mi primera pagina</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
 
 <h3>Primera página web: Cambiando colores a texto:</h3>
 
  <ol>
   <li style="color: red"><b>Texto en rojo.</b></li>
   <li style="color: green"><b>Texto en verde.</b></li>
   <li style="color: blue"><b>Texto en azul.</b></li>
  </ol>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Te recomiendo que mires algunos enlaces sobre html para que veas el funcionamiento de cada etiqueta y para que se utiliza.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: Pero la pregunta de su tarea es ambigua, ya que en su enunciado dice: "con al menos 3 párrafos" entonces debería usar la etiqueta `<p></p>` o no?

Comment: vale muchas gracias tambien por la ayudaa

Comment: para las listas no tenemos porque utilizar párrafos ya que la etiqueta <li> ya separa el texto en párrafos,